# Can I populate a range from one sheet to another in one workbook based on if a cell is equal to something specific?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, auto-populate

I Have a workbook that I am using to track inventory and purchasing. The initial sheet contains the "List" which identifies if something is in inventory or if it needs purchasing, there is a data validation for "Inventory" or "Purchase" in Column E. I want to populate another sheet within the same workbook, only rows that end with the "Purchase" value in column E.

For example:
In the sheet "List", if E2 is "Purchase", I want the sheet "Shopping" to populate with the values in List!A2:D2, I've tried a few combinations of If formulas and Arrayformula but haven't returned anything but Errors

I have tried in the shopping sheet, cell A2

```
=IF(List!E2"Purchase",List!A2:D2,blank)
=IF(List!E2"Purchase",Arrayformula(List!A2:d2),blank)
```

I've done a few other variations that I can't remember the exact order on but you get the gist of the ways I've tried it.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(List!E2="Purchase"; List!A2:D2; )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the filter function

```
=filter(List!A2:E,List!E2:E = "Purchase")
```